# Opening a CSV explicitly saved as UTF-8 still shows its encoding as cp1252

Tags: python, pandas, encoding

I have a Python script that generates a `.csv` file from given pandas `DataFrame`.
Even though in python3 the default `pandas.to_csv()` sets the encoding to `'utf-8'`, I also specify it in the code (after the file is generated):

```py
df.to_csv(filename, index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

I check the encoding type using:

```py
with open(filename) as f:
    print(f)
```

after which I get:  `encoding='cp1252'`

Could anyone help, Why is this the case?

Comment: Take a look at the [`open` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). Encoding for `open` is platform dependent.

Comment: Specifically: `encoding` is the name of the encoding used to decode or encode the file. This should only be used in text mode. The default encoding is platform dependent (whatever [`locale.getpreferredencoding()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding) returns), but any text encoding supported by Python can be used. See the [codecs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#module-codecs) module for the list of supported encodings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
with open(filename, encoding="utf8") as f:
    print(f)
```

Comment: Thanks. It is for sure useful for opening (reading) the file with specified 'utf-8' encoding
Found some additional info on https://www.py4u.net/discuss/191628
Qouting: 
In other words, Python opens source files as UTF-8 by default, but any interaction with the filesystem will depend on the environment. It's strongly recommended to use open(filename, encoding='utf-8') to read a file.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    print(f)
```

Comment: Thanks. It is for sure useful for opening (reading) the file with specified 'utf-8' encoding
Found some additional info on https://www.py4u.net/discuss/191628
Qouting: 
In other words, Python opens source files as UTF-8 by default, but any interaction with the filesystem will depend on the environment. It's strongly recommended to use open(filename, encoding='utf-8') to read a file.